# How to test Mocha & Chai + TypeScript + SystemJS + JSPM + Angular + Three.js

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, chai, jspm, systemjs

I'm working on a web-based 3D game. I have my project completely set up with **TypeScript**.

I have all my routing set up using **Angular**, and alongside I'm using **Three.js** as my 3D engine.

Finally, I have the **Mocha + Chai** combo to test my TypeScript using a particular plugin called [typescript-require](https://github.com/theblacksmith/typescript-require).

I use **Systemjs** as an importer for my **JSPM** packages.

So to set the stage:
(*Files are stripped down for example purposes*)

Systemjs/JSPM File: `jspmconfig.js`

```
System.config({

  ...

  paths: {

    ...

    "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*"

    ...

  },

  map: {

    ...

    "three.js": "github:mrdoob/three.js@master"

    ...

  }
});
```

Node File: `package.json`

```
...

"scripts": {
  "test": "mocha --compilers ts:typescript-require ./source/**/*.spec.ts"
},

...
```

Controller File: `QuestDetailCtrl.ts`:

```
/// <reference path="../../../../../typings/tsd.d.ts" />

// Controller | Dashboard
export default class QuestDetailCtrl {

    ... 

    // Constructor
    constructor() { ... }

    renderer: THREE.WebGLRenderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer(); // <-- This line uses a THREE instance.
}
```

**NOTE** *Somewhere a bit earlier in my app I already import **Three.js**, so it is available in my controller (this also compiles properly to ES5 and works in the browser).*

Mocha Test File `QuestDetailCtrl.spec.ts`

```
/// <reference path="../../../../../typings/tsd.d.ts" />

// Imports
import { assert, expect } from 'chai';
import QuestDetailCtrl from './QuestDetailCtrl';

// Describe
describe('QuestDetailCtrl', function() {

    // Shoulds
    it('should exist', () => {
        expect(QuestDetailCtrl).to.exist; // <-- WORKS
    });

    it('should initialize', () => {
        let instance = new QuestDetailCtrl(); // <-- DOES NOT WORK
    });

});
```

In the last file `QuestDetailCtrl.spec.ts`, I initialize a new instance of my controller (TypeScript class).

Because Mocha does not know about Three.js, this test fails on initializing the instance of my controller.

So my question becomes:

**How would I mock/import Three.js (or any other third party lib) inside my tests, such that Mocha knows about it and is able to test/initialize it?**

I guess similar situations are applicable to Angular when I start testing this, so a solution would be very much appreciated!

I already bumped into solutions where one would `import System from 'systemjs'` and set `meta` data to the `three.js` library to set `global` vars for System, but I couldn't get that to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think about two possibilities for now . I will write it in JS (es6) because Im not quite familiar with typescript and Jasmine but you can transform this in to mocha very easy.

> set global variable in your test

```
//QuestDetailCtrl.spec.ts
import THREE from 'three';
window.THREE = THREE;
// or just mock it window.THREE = {}. Its usually not a good thing to 
// import whole external library in your tests. If you will mock them, 
// don't forget to reset your mock before each test if you need a fresh mock
```

> import three as dependency in your script and mock it in your test

```
//QuestDetailCtrl.ts
import THREE from 'three';
export default class QuestDetailCtrl {
  constructor() { ... }

  renderer: THREE.WebGLRenderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer(); // <-- This line uses a THREE instance.
}

//===================================================================
//QuestDetailCtrl.spec.ts
// be aware, Im using jasmine 2 here. Im passing done value in to function because mocking dependencies are async. Im not sure how this can be done in mocha

beforeAll(done => {
  System.delete('three');

  System.set('absolute/and/normalized/three/path', System.newModule({
    WebGLRenderer: ()=>{},
  }));
  System.import('absolute/and/normalized/path/QuestDetailCtrl').then(module=>{
    ComponentBuilder = module;
    done();
  });
});
```

Hope thats help.

Comment: fyi, Mocha's [`before`](https://mochajs.org/#hooks) is the equivalent of Jasmine's [`beforeAll`](http://jasmine.github.io/2.1/introduction.html#section-10).

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't create instance of vendor dependencies in your test suite, as well you shouldn't create instances of tested class dependencies just mock it using for example [sinonjs](http://sinonjs.org).

Here you have my [example](https://github.com/b091/ts-skeleton) It do not have any complex test suite just trivial one (i'll try add some more complex soon) but it have Mocha & Chai & sinon + TypeScript + SystemJS + JSPM + Angular + ... :)